# How to Handle Undocumented Fields in OpenAPI Schema?

Tags: api-design, openapi

I'm working with an API that uses OpenAPI for its schema documentation. However, there are certain fields in the request body that shouldn't be visible to all consumers, for example, `internalProperty: bool`. These properties are crucial for some internal functionalities but aren't documented in the public-facing schema.

I've considered two approaches to manage these fields:

**1. Explicit Code Checks: The server-side code identifies and processes these fields specifically.**
**2. Dual Schemas: Use a public schema for external consumers and a private schema that includes the undisclosed fields for internal use.**

My primary concern is ensuring that the server handles these fields correctly without compromising security or performance.

**Is there a standard or recommended approach in the industry for managing such fields in OpenAPI? Are there specific pitfalls or challenges I should be aware of with either of the methods above?**

Comment: [My recommendation would be to have actual separate API endpoints for internal and external use](https://www.hyrumslaw.com/).

Comment: @PhilipKendall I personally would love to have separate API endpoints, as like in separate schema. But I don't want a customer seeing those. But the request validation algorithm **has** to somehow know that a parameter that is not allowed by the "public" schema is not an invalid one